# unable to type dynamic key in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have the following code form [this playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwBIBUsAUCywMAFhACZwDeAsAFBxwDiAolnALxwDkLWXANHQC+dOqEiw4MAJ5hgcAGJEAxsQAiAQxgaAPFk3aAfBzgAKOgygRkMYAHkoAIXLSA-AC44AZxhQAlogA5nAAPnDOZNIAkoh+8GEQAEYAVsDKMIL0cIkuHuEuMXGhcEmp6ZkAlBzGuFaofl7AegYaxciIZMAAZgHAZIaitOLQ8DJycACCObBKMKomplXsxgBuEH5kANyDw5IBtlBdGsrys6oAwhCoqBodXs1aGsY0WYFEnmfqjw9GFnAa0xgnimI0+wh24BGcH2wEOx3kAFVGp8AErALzIAA2MB+TxeDDIj08+kemUswAAjsh0UDFCpiJdrrcyPcSb9aCJaGJIZIxqd6WiMdi9ABpYDSBAgWx3OAAa3FEC6dLmDKuNzuuMM-DgbKeJnxcEJ2mJLWEcAAZFQ-gBteUSgI6sXSAC6nlu0nBXNoyggiB8cBu8owMBgYAAarDEoQSOQTLjtVho6QKKBpSy5QqlZ9GeqWZrDOYssQQ2Ak+RPNg8GWyJVqmYAj76kETY8Kh8BeisTjE0RkwmWsZllavQwfX74Khe+QvO2VTnmayB-q-gw3rTFnXalcGsAAHRQdEQTErYCmdqdHqIPoVMkMf6Azwbofn7q9Mh-IRwQaj33+ygHqkaSETwkWAVFO2FXVByoQ0iWhRBGwCQJtQA6kfE8ScY3TTk-jHf1G1zJ0TGLUNq13GAIAAGQgAB3WFzg0RoN0YnVq2-OA8PgEiwAUdplBMVCaWtAjmSdZ12M4uADyFWlwJkvRq37R5oOHO9YONeDEKCW8GGEtVRPFV04G43iENvHCsgPGBkCgRApIgmBPSAA):

```
export enum HTTPMethod {
  GET = 'GET',
}

export type FetchData<TData> = (
  routeOrBody?: string | BodyInit | object,
  body?: BodyInit | object,
) => Promise<TData | undefined>

export type AbortFetch = () => void;

export interface FetchCommands<TData> {
  get: FetchData<TData>
  abort: AbortFetch
}

export interface UseFetchResult<TData>{
  data: TData,
  request: FetchCommands<TData>
}

export type FetchResult<TKey extends keyof FetchCommands<TData>, TData> = {
  data: TData
} & {
  [key in TKey]: any
}

const makeHttpVerbMethod = <TData, TMethod extends keyof FetchCommands<TData>>(
  httpMethod: HTTPMethod,
) => (incoming: TData): FetchResult<TMethod, TData> => {

  const methods: FetchCommands<TData> = {
    get: () => Promise.resolve(undefined),
    abort: () => undefined
  } 

  const {request}: UseFetchResult<TData> = { data: incoming, request: methods }

  const commandKey = httpMethod.toLowerCase() as TMethod

  const httpFunc = request[commandKey]


  const result: FetchResult<TMethod, TData> =  {
    data: incoming,
    [commandKey]: httpFunc,
  }

  return result
}
```

Basically, I want to add a key to what is returned from the `makeHttpVerbMethod` function but I am not entirely sure it is possible, I am using a generic type argument to try and constrain what the key could be called:

```
const makeHttpVerbMethod = <TData, TMethod extends keyof FetchCommands<TData>>(
  httpMethod: HTTPMethod,
) => (incoming: TData): FetchResult<TMethod, TData> => {
```

I want to add a dynamic key to the return type from `makeHttpVerbMethod`

But I think tsc is getting confused because I get this error message when trying to assign to `result`.

> Type '{ [x: string]: TData | FetchCommands[TMethod]; data: TData; }' is not assignable to type 'FetchResult'.
>     Type '{ [x: string]: TData | FetchCommands[TMethod]; data: TData; }' is not assignable to type '{ [key in TMethod]: any; }'.

I don't understand where `{ [x: string]` is coming from

If I change the function to use an explicit `'get'` literal then it all works

```
const makeHttpVerbMethod = <TData, TMethod extends keyof FetchCommands<TData>>(
  httpMethod: HTTPMethod,
) => (incoming: TData): FetchResult<'get', TData> => {

  const methods: FetchCommands<TData> = {
    get: () => Promise.resolve(undefined),
    abort: () => undefined
  } 

  const {request}: UseFetchResult<TData> = { data: incoming, request: methods }

  const commandKey = 'get'

  const httpFunc = request[commandKey]

  const result: FetchResult<'get', TData> =  {
    data: incoming,
    [commandKey]: httpFunc,
  }

  return result
}
```

Is there a way of making this work with a parameterised type TMethod?

Comment: Is this really a [*minimal* reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?  There's a lot of stuff here to wade through and it would help to remove anything not directly relevant to your issue.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz that is a fair point, I'll weed it down

Comment: Is that any better @jcalz

Comment: *I don't understand where { [x: string] is coming from*: the `x` is a placeholder created by TS, [here's](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvA2gawiAXFAZ2ACcBLAOwHMBdfAQ3JAF8BuAWAChRIoAhO4sjRYcUCoRIUa9Rq05A) another place where it can be observed (hover over `Bar`)

Comment: @NinoFiliu I don't understand the error message in the blockquote in my question.  I don't think I've heard of this placeholder before.  I don't even know if it is fixable.

Comment: I've updated the question, if I replace `TMethod` wtih the literal `'get'` then it compiles.  I am very confused

Answer (score 0):

One of the issues here seems to be a [known bug](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948) whereby objects with computed properties like `{[commandKey]: httpFunc}` have their keys widened to a [string index](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types), which is why the compiler complains about `string` not matching `TMethod`.  It works when you replace with just `"get"` because a computed key of a single string-literal type isn't widened to `string`.  Right now there's no fix for this; there are just workarounds.

The workaround I'd suggest here would be to use a helper function which takes a key of type `K` and a value of type `V` and returns an object of type `Record<K, V>` (meaning the key is `K` and the value is `V`):

```
function keyValue<K extends keyof any, V>(key: K, value: V) {
  const ret = {} as Record<K, V>;
  ret[key] = value;
  return ret;
}
```

This is only type safe if `K` is known to only be a single key type and not a union:

```
const goodUseOfKeyValue = keyValue("hey", "you"); // {hey: "you"}

const notGoodUseOfKeyValue = keyValue(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "oh" : "no", 1);
// supposedly type {oh: number, no: number},
// but of course it's really {oh: number} | {no: number}
```

(That could be fixed so that `notGoodUseOfKeyValue` is correctly typed, but we don't need it here since you intend `TMethod` to be a single string literal).

Now we will use that and `Object.assign()` instead of using computed properties:

```
  const result: FetchResult<TMethod, TData> = Object.assign(
    { data: incoming },
    keyValue(httpMethod, request[httpMethod])
  ); // okay, no error
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwBIBUsAUCywMAFhACZwDeAsAFBxwDiAolnALxwBELWXdAXzp1QkWHBgBPMMDgAxIgGNiAEQCGMNQB4s6zQD4OcABR0GUCMhjAA8lABC5SQH4AXHADOMKAEtEAczgAHzhHMkkASUQfeBCIACMAK2BFGAAaMzh4pzdQpyiY4LgE5NS6AEoOQ1wLVB8PYB09NSLkRDJgADM-YDJ9AG5hWlFoeCkZOABBbNgFGGUjY0r2QwA3CB8yQdoRcFG4P2soTrVFWTnlAGEIVFQ1do8mjTVDGno4fyJ3C9Vnp4Ntgw1DMYO5pqMftshDthntxIdgMdTrIAKoNH4AJWAHmQABsYP8XlRMmRnu5dM9AXAoMAAI7IbGg+RKYjXW73MiPCkAwRDEbicbnFlYnH4nQAaWAkgQIGsDzgAGspRBOsz5qybncHoT9Gk4NyiZw3gxSZpyc0oXAAGRUOAAbSV0r8+slkgAuu57tKBNs6AB6P3FRC46XIBoSYj1A6q8UHDxwRAQeAxBq41UtNo+CCICTSYB0TptVJZnOOgBqalxDK0sdAcs5iuV6cQkj1Zf0xkd7nFetWlYZ7jLlWNcEU2a81KIRkoAjganjWLHUDINbbA0yNJgDqlbqMfarwCpm+QUBzm6hQzHiAn-gg5DRtk6rorB6M5f7wGMXGIUq4eq4kiWFw5T9HAAZUD+kjuABQHQnQV4TomMCMHeZAPjYT5Si+DJvlhH7GPgGjEAAdFAHI3EscBaHAAAMxEAKxwM43AQMQXBwNBiZ-nAACMIH+oGOJgJADRkCGuYTJQrHuCgqDxIieqJjJaDyVAAgZLQ4HxFYxSqmOJ7hjEADk8Y0pW4lScQylyYis4hJQSkJiptmXuO8B3EqGAwDAYBloi8SECQ5BGISepYIFpAUHWSANo6KpqlcmoclyzT6B2mTEN5YAReQ5I5WQFRVCYfhjnUATms85TfMK2J4gS4VEJFYWpUVI4Ie5jXkB41XqmyWqcjq06ZAwnxMpRKxwDUNz1MApHYhAuKrJ+bQdN0iC9OUGkMECILuONhgrV0PQFe8PpDAw7W2jS9KMnAAjuA+mK1WKBqGEaw1wKaajuCV00BFt23XQyXjuKgnWcpkZ0whdbmTqKTJPfDOj5c1zxvXANhJCkMDEfOHg+P4iCmO8DCUJ9ZIHIgpV+IE6kfe+B7GJlPko5ON1eHazPZeDbrlJk-HQ5OMAnmez0wFC2xAA)